# How to parse an array in PHP to fill NULL as average between two closest values

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, null

Im trying to parse an array in PHP to fill Null values as averages between the closest two values before inserting into MySQL (5). I have currently tried the below code but the code moves the pointer for the entire array when I call next($value['wind']).

f_data:

```
(
 [2019-05-06 09:00:00] => Array
  (
  [temp] => 50
  [wind] => 10
  [rain] => 50
  )

 [2019-05-06 10:00:00] => Array
  (
  [temp] => 65
  )
 [2019-05-06 11:00:00] => Array
  (
  [temp] => 70
  [wind] => 8
  [rain] => 30
  )
)
```

code thus far:

```
foreach ($f_data as $key => $value) {

    $f_weather_date = $key;
    $future_weather = $value['temp'];
    if ($value['wind'] > 0) {
        $f_wind = $value['wind'];
        $f_wind_last = $f_wind;
    } else {

        $f_wind = $f_wind_last;

        $x = 0;
        $f_wind_next = 0;

       for ($x = 0; $f_wind_next = 0; $x++) {
            $f_wind_next = next($value['wind']);
            return $x; 
    } 

    $f_wind = ($f_wind_next + $f_wind_last) / $x;

    }

    if ($value['rain'] > 0) {
        $f_rain = $value['rain'];
        $f_rain_last = $f_rain; 

    } else {

    $f_rain = $f_rain_last;

    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `Table` (`Date`, `Temp`, `Wind`, `Rain`) VALUES ('$f_weather_date', $future_weather, $f_wind, $f_rain)";


    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

}
```

Expected results would return [wind] => 9 and [rain] => 40 at 10:00:000

Comment: The argument to `next()` is supposed to be an array. `$value['wind']` is a number.

Comment: The `for` loop will exit the function on the first iteration when it does `return $x;`

Comment: Return in the for loop will exit the function. And I recommend create array with int keys - add the average data on him (now it is O(1) as accessing last and next is simple) and then return the original keys back

Comment: Faking data on input poisons the data for any other use. If you just want a graph without holes fill in the gaps before giving the data to your graphing library instead, or find one that does this for you.

Comment: @pbjork Did my post helped you? did you understood how to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

First extract the keys and then iterate with int key. This way you can calculate the average easily.

Consider:

```
$keys = array_keys($f_data);
$arr = array_values($f_data);

foreach($arr as $k => &$v) { 
    if (!isset($v['rain']) { //you can do the same for wind
        $v = ($arr[$k -1]['rain'] + $arr[$k +1]['rain']) /2;
    } 
}
```

Now return the original keys with:

```
$f_data = array_combine($keys, $arr);
```

Notice you need to take care of case the last eleme t is missing data and when 2 neighbors elements missing data